# Is there a JavaScript reload() equivalent in Elm

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I want to build a button that when clicked will refresh the page (i.e. command+r shortcut on your keyboard). Is there a reload() (JavaScript) equivalent function in Elm. If not, how should I go about creating this button?

Answer (score 12):

https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Navigation#reload

There are two commands in the Navigation package to achieve exactly this.

```
Browser.Navigation.reload : Cmd msg

Browser.Navigation.reloadAndSkipCache : Cmd msg
```

Just use them in your update function

```
import Browser.Navigation as Navigation

[...]

update msg model = case msg of 
     [...]
     ReloadBtnClicked -> (model, Navigation.reload)
     [...]
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a port like

reload -> Cmd msg

and having it call the JS yourself, see above post about using elm lang navigation package.

Comment: This is incorrect, the elm-lang/navigation package provides [a `reload` function](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/navigation/2.1.0/Navigation#reload)